# Python: Functions - carry the results from one function into another

Tags: python, function

i have two functions. The first function - def training_list() creates two lists - under_50k & over_50k. I would like the second function def sums_lists() to create a sum_list which adds up each index within both lists and then appends each list to create 1 list - sums_list. when i run the code, it says over_50k is not defined in the sums_list function. Can you please tell me how i define this, i want to carry over the under_50k & over_50k list into the new function

---

- error message

  `File "C:\Python34\Lib\assign1.py", line 208, in sums_list over_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*over_50k)] NameError: name 'over_50k' is not defined`

---

```
def training_list():

    data_list = create_data(data_url)
    training_list = data_list[:int(len(data_list) * 75 / 100)]
    test_list = data_list[int(len(data_list) * 25 / 100):]

    #return training_list


    over_50k = []
    over_50k_count = 0
    under_50k = []
    under_50k_count = 0

    for row in training_list:
        if row[-1].lstrip() == '<=50K':
            under_50k.append(row[:-1])
            under_50k_count +=1
        elif row [-1].lstrip() == ">50K":
            over_50k.append(row[:-1])
            over_50k_count +=1


    return under_50k,over_50k

def sums_list():

    over_50k_sum_list = []
    under_50k_sum_list = []

    over_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*over_50k)]
    under_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*under_50k)]
    sums_list = over_50k_sum_list + under_50k_sum_list

    print(sums_list)
    return sums_list

def main():
    def trainging_list():

        over_50k = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 8]]
        under_50k = [[1, 4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 4, 5], [6, 9, 4, 5]]
        print(over_50k)
        return over_50k, under_50k

    over_50k, under_50k = trainging_list()

    def sum_columns(over_50k, under_50k):
        print("a")
        over_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*over_50k)]
        under_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*under_50k)]
        sums = over_50k_sum_list + under_50k_sum_list
        print(sums)
        return sums
main()
```

Comment: pass the arrays as parameters to `sums_list`.

Comment: Hi akonsu, from my example what would i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

under_50k and over_50k have only been assigned within your first function. You need to call that function in order for them to exist when you call the second function. Adding:

```
under_50k, over_50k = training_list()
```

after your first function would work as they have then been assigned as global variables.

You can also add in arguments when defining the second function that are then read into it when it is called.

```
def sums_list(under_50k, over_50k):
    # rest of the function
```

Then call one function then the other in unindented space:

```
p, q = training_list
sums_list(p ,q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main programme needs to call `training_list`, store the values that are returned, and pass them to `sums_list`.

```
def main():
    under_50k, over_50k = training_list()
    sums = sums_list(under_50k, over_50k)
```

But it may be simplest to reduce `sums_list` to just

```
def sum_columns(table):
    return [sum(column) for column in zip(*table)]
```

and call it using `sum_columns(under_50k + over_50k)`. (I would prefer the name `sum_columns` because it makes it easier to understand what it is doing.)

Comment: Hi Stuart, trying to follow the first part of your comment. I've added an update to the code. Just trying to get an easy example to work first. I added the def main() function and also the under 50k, over_50k = training_list(). Im getting the following error:   File "C:/Python34/Lib/rerun.py", line 12, in main
    over_50k, under_50k = trainging_list()
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: Your function `trainging_list` returns a variable called `trainging_list` without assigning any value to it. So python looks for what you could be referring to, and finds that the function itself is called `trainging_list` and returns that. You need to explicitly set the value of the variable you return. And normally you shouldn't give the name of a variable within a function the same name as the variable itself, as that causes confusion.

Comment: Ok thanks Stuart, i've amended the code and changed the return variables. I'm able to generate the print over_50k list and then the process finishes with exit code 0. It doesnt seem to jump into the next function

Comment: No, the code inside functions only runs when you call the function, e.g. `print(sum_columns(over_50k, under_50k))`

Comment: Stuart, thanks a million, i've been trying to figure it out all day. Thank you thank you thank you